# nvim-treesitter をインストールしたが、TSInstall などのコマンドが使えない. E492

Tags: vim, neovim

neovim に vim-plug を用いて nvim-treesitter をインストールし, `:TSInstall` や `:TSUpgrade` などのコマンドを叩くと, `E492: エディタのコマンドではありません`というエラーが出てしまいます.

nvim-treesitter 自体のインストールは問題なく完了し, `:checkhealth`でも問題があるようには見えません.
どのようにしたらこれらのコマンドが使えるようになるでしょうか.

nvim-treesitterに関するcheckhealth:
[image: checkhealth1]

vim.treesitterに関するcheckhealth:
[image: checkhealth2]

neovim:

```
:version
NVIM v0.7.0
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by brew@HMBRW-A-001-M1-002.local

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

      システム vimrc: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
       省略時の $VIM: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/neovim/0.7.0/share/nvim"
```

treesitter自体はhomebrewを使ってインストールしました.

Comment: 結局devバージョンに変更してもtreesitterが使えるようにならなかったので、
nvim.initを全てluaで書き直し、luaのプラグインを入れてneovim環境を刷新しました。

Answer (score 1):

僕も0.7にした途端、様々な不具合が出ました。
[OgaKen さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/88714) を試しても治りませんでした。

ただ、neovim nightly のバージョンにアップデートしたらすべてのエラーが解決して問題なく使えるようになりました。
一度試してみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
やはり、nightlyバージョンにアップデートする必要があるのですね。
nvim-treesitterのgithubではあくまでも'recommended'とだけあるので、通常バージョンでもいけるものだと期待（横着）していました。
とりあえず今はSemshiを使って作業しています。プロジェクトが落ち着いたらnightlyバージョンに変更試してみたいと思います。